# Apply restrictions to publishers on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, security

We have added a specific AD group to the  publisher role on our ArcGIS Server, which is version 10.1.  We also created a folder that has its security settings restricted to this same AD group.  We would like this group to have the ability to publish services, but restrict their ability to publish to just this single folder that their AD group has access to.  Unfortunately, it seems that once a group is added to the publisher role, they are able to access all services on the server and publish in any folder.  Is there a way to restrict where a publisher group can publish services to a single folder and also restrict their access to just the services in that folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**.

From esri's website:

> If a role's type is set to either Administrator or Publisher, that
>   role automatically gets implicit access permission **to all GIS web
>   services hosted on the ArcGIS Server site**. This implicit permission
>   **cannot be overridden by changing the permissions on a service or
>   folder**.

[REFERENCE LINK](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/restricting-access-to-arcgis-server.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I added alread a FeatureRequets for this on ideas.esri.com:

**ArcGIS Server: New role like 'mapservice-manage' to associate on a folder and/or mapservice** 
http://shar.es/1fVxvl

Just vote for it. May be it will be considered :-)

Comment: Excellent, This is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Esri "Bug" number. NIM086293.

The status is "Closed: Will not be addressed".